# BroadcastReceiver's onReceive() not invoked for Alarm

Tags: android

I have been trying to setup an Alarm, with a BroadcastReceiver that is invoked when the alarm is triggered. Spent hours on this, but I am unable to get the onReceive() to be called.

Somehow this works nicely on API 21, but consistently fails on API 18, which is where I want this to work.

---

dumpsys alarm

```
RTC_WAKEUP #2: Alarm{b1fc3710 type 0 srk.test.broadcastreceiver}

type=0 when=-12s1ms repeatInterval=0 count=0

operation=PendingIntent{b1afd430: PendingIntentRecord{b1fc7c28 srk.test.broadcastreceiver broadcastIntent}}
```

---

manifest

```
<application ...> 

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
        ...
    <receiver
        android:name="srk.test.broadcastreceiver.Receiver"
                android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="srk.test.broadcastreceiver.alarm_intent" >
                    </action>
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

---

Activity

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent("srk.test.broadcastreceiver.alarm_intent");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 123456789,
                            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (2 * 1000), pendingIntent);

        Log.i("SRK", "Alarm Scheduled ... ");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

---

Receiver

public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i("SRK", "Alarm Triggered!");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

---

I am testing on Android Studio on Windows with an Emulator for Nexus 5, API 18.

I hope this level of detail is enough for reproducing this issue. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Activity

```
     Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

     Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BroadcastReceiver .class);
                    String strAction = "srk.test.broadcastreceiver.alarm_intent";
                    intent.setAction(strAction);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 123456789,
                        intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (2 * 1000), pendingIntent);

    Log.i("SRK", "Alarm Scheduled ... ");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 });
```

Reciever

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

if(intent.getAction().equals("srk.test.broadcastreceiver.alarm_intent")){
Log.i("SRK", "Alarm Triggered!");
Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}}}
```

You need to set intent action as you have added in to your manifest file 
Try this code it will sure helps you